# Max Farming in Dark Souls III

Tags: dark-souls-3

What is the maximum possible item discovery level in Dark Souls III, with 99 luck, Symbol of Avarice, etc. In short, every possible thing you can do to increase item discovery and what is the maximum number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the Wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Item+Discovery):

> The highest possible Item Discovery is **599**, when equipped with two Crystal Sage's Rapiers, the Symbol of Avarice, the Gold Serpent Ring +2, using a Rusted Gold Coin and having 99 Luck.

As pointed out in the comments, if you have the Ringed City DLC, you can get a [Gold Serpent Ring +3](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Covetous+Gold+Serpent+Ring), raising the max by 15 to **614**.

Comment: With the Ringed City DLC, there is now a Gold Serpent Ring +3, which gives 115 item discovery, 15 more than the +2 version.

Comment: @fhl thanks for the information! I edited my answer.

Comment: Don't think it won't still take for-freaking-ever to farm Concords, though. -_-